# Setting elements of a 3d array to zero in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I do have a three dimensional array `A(m,n,t)`, (8 x 60 x 8), filled with positive numbers.

What I am trying to do is to set every element of this array to zero if the third index (t) is smaller than the first (m).
So for examle A(5,42,3) should be set to 0 as m=5 > t=3. However A(5,13,7) should not be changed, hence m=5 <= t=7.

If one would look at `squeeze(A(:,val,:))` where val is any number from 1 to 60, then what I am trying to do is to set the lower triangular matrix to zero.

My approach was a loop over the first index doing

```
for ii=2:8
  A(ii,:,1:ii-1)=0;
end
```

However this uses a loop and I am almost certain there should be a (smart) way without it.
So how does one do this without the use of a loop?

Comment: Are you sure that loop does what you want it to...? If it does, and I'm sure it does not, but if it does then you can replace the loop with `A(2:8, :, 1:7) = 0;`

Comment: I agree.It looks like you are not comparing `m` or `t` at all...

Comment: And do you mean comparing indices or the values at those indices?

Comment: I do mean comparing indices. Unless I didn't mess up something in my head the loop should work, as I know the indices smaller then the first index once I fix the first one in the loop.

Comment: Your loop is not comparing indices.

Comment: I am iterating over the first dimension of the array (m). In each iteration m is fixed so all values of t which are smaller then m have to be 1:(m-1). As the loop ranges from the first to the last element of my first dimension I sould get every element that has to be set to 0. Or am I mistaken? Besides index is still the position of the element in the array, right (same in english as in german)?

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully make it more clear, what I am trying to do. I still can't find where the code above is wrong though. @kkuilla Could you show me the right way? Maybe I get it if I see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62276/discussion-between-firefoxmetzger-and-kkuilla).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
[xg,yg,zg]=ndgrid(1:size(arr,1),1:size(arr,2),1:size(arr,3));
arr(xg>zg)=0;
```